# NewRelic Integration With Spring Boot Using io.micrometer

Tags: java, spring-boot, newrelic, spring-micrometer, spring-actuator

I have installed the NewRelic agent on MacOS and configured the spring boot application by following [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.export.newrelic) and few other links. Also tried telemetry micrometer configuration.
Thing I want to achieve is to integrate spring boot application without installing java agent and register under APM.
Below is my configuration:

```yaml
management:  
    metrics:
        export:
            newrelic:
            api-key: <Tried all the keys> ()
            account-id: 
            enabled: true
            step: 30s
```

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-new-relic</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Error:

```
ERROR [new-relic-metrics-publisher] io.micrometer.newrelic.NewRelicInsightsApiClientProvider: failed to send metrics to new relic: http 403 {}
```

I tried to debug the provider NewRelicInsightsApiClientProvider to check what is being passed as Stream of events, everything looks good to me. The insightsEndpoint is "https://insights-collector.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/ACCOUNT-ID/events" I even tried to change with "https://insights-collector.eu01.nr-data.net" did not help.

Need some help here, not sure what am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration which worked for me

```yaml
  metrics:
    export:
      newrelic:
        api-key: #insights key 
        account-id: #<account-id>
        enabled: true
        step: 30s #duration at which events will be published to new relic
        #uri: https://insights-collector.eu01.nr-data.net #URI of the data center
        uri: https://metric-api.eu.newrelic.com
        serviceName: <service name>
```

As mentioned by @André Onuki generate your insights key from right side of the new relic's API keys page, [More Details](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/intro-apis/new-relic-api-keys/).
NewRelicInsightsApiClientProvider uses a default URI which did not work for me, so I looked up for the [Data Center URI](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/accounts/accounts-billing/account-setup/choose-your-data-center/). To identify the data center, check your license key if it starts with "eu" then it's **European**.
Start your application, check under APM & Services section of NewRelic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the key you should use there is an Insights insert key. This key is located in a different location from other keys.

If you go to the page where you have your regular keys, you'll find a link to the Insights keys.
[image: insights key location]

Alternatively, you could also use New Relic's [Micrometer registry](https://github.com/newrelic/micrometer-registry-newrelic). This is a different implementation of the registry created by New Relic.

Comment: I had tried insights insert key as well. No luck. As I mentioned in my post I had used telemetry configuration as well. The one you had shared.

Comment: Sorry, since that key is kinda hidden, I thought you might have overlooked it.

Comment: Did you double check the account id in the URL?

Comment: Yes I did. It's correct.

Comment: I found the answer and posted it, there was some configuration mismatch. Thanks for the help.